# What does "it always picks up" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "it" refer to here? RECOVERY FROM RECESSIONS

“In economic booms, **it** always picks up, but **it** never picks up as far as the previous peak,” Deaton said. “You get this endless downward ratchet. That’s something we really need to turn around, and it’s going to be hard.”

https://fortune.com/2021/04/12/taxing-wealthy-pay-for-covid-recovery-bad-idea-nobel-prize-winning-economist/

Comment: The speaker seems to be speaking very informally and imprecisely.  I think he just means *the economy in general*.  We sometimes say "it" or "things" to refer to general conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "In economic booms, it always picks up, but it never picks up as far as the previous peak,” Deaton said. “You get this endless downward ratchet. That’s something we really need to turn around, and it’s going to be hard.”

We get the meaning from context that *it* refers to the *economy*, not 'recovery from recessions', though.

Strictly said, there is a pronoun-antecedent rule infringement as the pronoun *it* has no clear antecedent; if *economic booms* is used as the antecedent, the passage will be awkward.